# Do all variables in a class have to start with self. or class.?

Tags: python, class

If I have intermediate variables that just help with the multiple steps within a method and won't ever be used outside the method, do I still need to prepend `self.` to the variable? For instance:

```
class apples:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def add(self):
        self.z = str(self.x + self.y) + " apples"
        return self.z

foo = apples(3, 5).add
```

Does `self.z` need to start with `self.` or can it just be defined as `z`?

Comment: Just `z` is fine.

Comment: Probably a typo, but you need to _call_ `foo = apples(3, 5).add()`.

Answer (score 3):

No. `self.` is for variables you'd like to persist on the instance and `cls.` is for variables you'd like to persist on the class. Variables that should be destroyed when the method ends are just like variables in a function.

In your example, you could just do

```
    def add(self):
        z = str(self.x + self.y) + " apples"
        return z
```

But since `z` is only there to hold the return value, you shouldn't use it at all. This avoids a store followed by a load before return.

```
class apples:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def add(self):
        return str(self.x + self.y) + " apples"

foo = apples(3, 5).add()
```